# Is it possible to change HDMI mode without rebooting?

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, raspbian-buster

I would like to try different combinations of `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` without having to reboot.

Hardware and OS: Pi3B on Rasbian buster

Comment: Give us a clue? Which operating system? Which Pi?

Comment: @CoderMike Sorry about that. Added hardware and OS to question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume RPi 4 with Raspbian Buster.

While you can't really change the group and mode, you can change the resolution and refresh rate. In menu --> preferences, there is an app called 'Screen Configuration' and you can use that to adjust the display.